# How do I detect Arabic character in UITextField?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

I am a beginner programmers iPhone.(swfit)
How do I prevent the user does not use Arabic words in the text field?
In other words, how do I detect Arabic character?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can regex

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^A-Za-z0-9 \\-\\.\\:\\/]", options: [])

let firstMatch = regex.rangeOfFirstMatchInString(yourString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, yourString.characters.count))

if firstMatch.location != NSNotFound {
    // Invalid character found
}
```